# Loading specific bootstrap mode in hook_menu

Tags: 6, routes

There is a way to define a specific bootstrap mode for a hook_menu URL (MENU_CALLBACK)?

I just want the request returns to me a result of a simple query in JSON and for that, I don´t need load the Drupal bootstrap in full mode, damaging the response performance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, because `hook_menu()` is invoked when Drupal is completely bootstrapped, also because only when Drupal has been completely bootstrapped, all the modules are loaded; only in this case all the menu callbacks defined in `hook_menu()` are available.

If you really need to limit the bootstrap to a phase, then you can write a file that is similar to [index.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/index.php/7), for example.

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
menu_execute_active_handler();
```

An example of file used for a specific task is [cron.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/cron.php/7).

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

if (!isset($_GET['cron_key']) || variable_get('cron_key', 'drupal') != $_GET['cron_key']) {
  watchdog('cron', 'Cron could not run because an invalid key was used.', array(), WATCHDOG_NOTICE);
  drupal_access_denied();
}
elseif (variable_get('maintenance_mode', 0)) {
  watchdog('cron', 'Cron could not run because the site is in maintenance mode.', array(), WATCHDOG_NOTICE);
  drupal_access_denied();
}
else {
  drupal_cron_run();
}
```

Generally, there isn't the need to limit the bootstrap, only to serve data in JSON format. Creating a file like cron.php should be done for a dedicated task that is time consuming, or for limiting the pages being served, as with install.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/js
It does not let you choose the bootstrap level, but it allows you to define a callback that only loads the bare bone of drupal.